# Approximately, how many years before marrying muhammad was Aisha engaged to jubayr ibn Mutim?

Tags: history, aisha

As a rough estimate, how many years before marrying muhammad was Aisha first engaged to jubayr bin mutim?

Comment: I think [Was Aisha ra engagede before she married Muhammad saw](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35128/was-aisha-r-a-engaged-before-she-married-prophet-muhammad-s-a-w) is relevant.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but i wasnt able to find any date of aisha and jubayr's engagement

Comment: Are you expecting a date description from a time span where being illiterate was common?

Comment: i do not expect any date given to be accurate, i wanted a range or estimate. just something. anything.

Comment: I doubt that such an estimate is available as it is a trivial detail and has no direct relevance to Islam.

Comment: Even the birth date of our prophet () is only known based on an event which is only approximately dated beside this there's even a difference of opinion on his age of death. As the engagement with Jubayr is irrelevant to Islam or the biography of our prophet () these details wouldn't have found any reception by early historians. So it might be the matter of months, weeks etc.. All we can safely say it was before the engagement with Muhammad (). It could even have been before the revelation started. As it is hard to believe that believing parents would give their daughter to a disbeliever.